# Extract xml from api.hostip.info. Minidom works on local GAE but not Google GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, minidom

Trying to upload xml latitude, longitude coordinates from api.hostip.info. Python minidom works fine in local GAE (and iPython) but does not work in Google GAE. I can throw the code below but I think I'm missing something specific to Google GAE in extracting xml from another website.

```
ip = self.request.remote_addr
IP_URL = "http://api.hostip.info/?="
def get_coords(ip):
    url = IP_URL + ip
    xml = None
    try:
        xml = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        return "in URLError "+ e.code   
    try:
        if xml:
            s = minidom.parseString(xml)
        else:
            return "unable to parse content"
    except:
        return "exception error unable to parse content"
    try:
        if s:
            coords = s.getElementsByTagName("gml:coordinates")
        else:
            return "unable to get coords"
    except:
        return "exception error unable to get coords"
    try:    
        if coords:  #Google GAE fails on this if statement
            p = coords[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        else:
            return "unable to get node value- points"
    except:
        return "exception unable to get node-value points"
    try:
        lon, lat = coords[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.split(',')
        points = [Point(lat,lon)]
        return points
    except:
        return "unable to return points"  
    return None + "dropped to bottom"
```

Comment: Would there be any further info in the logs?

Comment: Not that I can see - 

    2013-08-29 09:40:21.676 / 200 11ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0

    76.181.140.45 - - [29/Aug/2013:09:40:21 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 345 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" "xxxxxx.appspot.com" ms=11 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000051 app_engine_release=1.8.3 instance=00c61b117c810837b8e38a1bab7f69b5fc92

Comment: Hm, you're getting a `200 Ok` status, what is the page load displaying?

Comment: Google GAE -unable to get node value- points. Local GAE - [Point(lat=u'39.9889', lon=u'-82.9874')]

Comment: Problem solved. api.hostip.info not generating location based on sent IP address except on a one or two time basis. ap.host.info ignores IP address given and then defaults to ip location of sender. I used a different IP geolocator api and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. api.hostip.info not generating location based on sent IP address except on a one or two time basis. ap.host.info ignores IP address given and then defaults to ip location of sender. I used a different IP geolocator api and it worked fine